# Executing INSERT from Identity column Output in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, executenonquery

Using VB.NET and SQL Server: I have a table `[Item_List]`. When I add a new item from a Windows form, I want to insert the record into the `Item_List` table, get the `ItemID` which is an `IDENTITY`, and use that to insert a corresponding record into the financial tracking `[Inventory_Transactions]` table.

I tested the following query directly in a T-SQL query window with success:

```
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (ItemID INT);

INSERT INTO [Item_List] (Item_Name, Vendor, Quantity, Price, Category, Active, Notes, Created) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ItemID INTO @OutputTbl(ItemID) 
VALUES ('Test Item', 'Walmart', 42, 4.22, 'Stuff', 1, '', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO Inventory_Transactions (TransDate, Category, Transactee, Amount, Item, Quantity, Description) 
    SELECT 
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Stuff', 'Walmart', -4.22, ItemID, 42, '';
```

However when I try to run using `ExecuteNonQuery()` I get an error

> Invalid column name 'ItemID'

I've used the exact script from above and also below with parameters - same error.

```
Dim sql As String = "DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (ItemID INT); " &
                    "INSERT INTO [Item_List] (Item_Name, Vendor, Quantity, Price, Category, Active, Notes, Created) " &
                    "OUTPUT INSERTED.ItemID  INTO @OutputTbl(ItemID) " &
                    "VALUES (@ItemName, @Vendor, @Quantity, @Price, @Category, @Active, @Notes, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); " &
                    "INSERT INTO Inventory_Transactions (TransDate, Category, Transactee, Amount, Item, Quantity, Description) " &
                    "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @Category, @Vendor, '-' + @Price, ItemID, @Quantity, @Notes;"

Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.dbConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

        If Not IsNothing(params) Then
            For Each param In params
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
            Next
        End If

        If cmd.Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then 
           cmd.Connection.Open()

        Dim rows As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

How can I implement this in VB?

Comment: i'd recommend putting it all inside one stored proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this:

```
"SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @Category, @Vendor, '-' + @Price, ItemID, @Quantity, @Notes;"
```

should be:

```
"SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @Category, @Vendor, '-' + @Price, ItemID, @Quantity, @Notes from @OutputTbl;"
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this code and it worked exactly as expected:

```vb
Dim sql = "INSERT INTO Parent (ParentName) VALUES (@ParentName);
           INSERT INTO Child (ChildName, ParentId) VALUES (@ChildName, SCOPE_IDENTITY())"

command.CommandText = sql
command.Parameters.Add("@ParentName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "Parent1"
command.Parameters.Add("@ChildName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "Child1"

command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The `SCOPE_IDENTITY` function gets the last identity value generated in the current scope.

If you need to use the identity value multiple times then you can assign it to a parameter and use that, e.g.

```vb
Dim sql = "INSERT INTO Parent (ParentName) VALUES (@ParentName);
           SELECT @ParentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
           INSERT INTO Child (ChildName, ParentId) VALUES (@ChildName, @ParentId)"

command.CommandText = sql
command.Parameters.Add("@ParentName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "Parent1"
command.Parameters.Add("@ParentId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
command.Parameters.Add("@ChildName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "Child1"

command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If you need to use the identity value in your VB code then also use a parameter like this:

```vb
Dim parentSql = "INSERT INTO Parent (ParentName) VALUES (@ParentName);
                 SELECT @ParentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();"

parentCommand.CommandText = parentSql
parentCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParentName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "Parent1"
parentCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParentId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

parentCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Dim childSql = "INSERT INTO Child (ChildName, ParentId) VALUES (@ChildName, @ParentId)"

childCommand.CommandText = childSql
childCommand.Parameters.Add("@ChildName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "Child1"
childCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = parentCommand.Parameters("@ParentId").Value

childCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```